# Check a word in a list and create a new variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, dataframe

I want to get de location that is inside obras desc using the list of citys that I have in a list.

I have the following dataframe

```
obras = pd.DataFrame([['1','Agua de Buenos Aires'],['2', 'Sistenas de carreteras Jujuy'],['3','Reasentamiento en Entre Ríos'], ['4','Rutas en Córdoba']],
columns = ['id', 'desc'])
```

And the list

`list = ['Buenos Aires', 'Jujuy', Corrientes', 'Entre Ríos']`

I try to do this

```
for s in obras["desc"]:if any(xs in s for xs in list):obras['Localidad'] = s
```

The expected result would be:

| id | desc | localidad |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Agua de Buenos Aires | Buenos Aires |
| 2 | Sistenas de carreteras | Jujuy |
| 3 | Reasentamiento en Entre Ríos | Entre Ríos |
| 4 | Rutas en Córdoba | NaN |

But the result I get is:

| id | desc | localidad |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Agua de Buenos Aires | Reasentamiento en Entre Ríos |
| 2 | Sistenas de carreteras | Reasentamiento en Entre Ríos |
| 3 | Reasentamiento en Entre Ríos | Reasentamiento en Entre Ríos |
| 4 | Rutas en Córdoba | Reasentamiento en Entre Ríos |

How I can solve this problem?

thanks!!!

Comment: Where is the NaN coming from?

Comment: That is no cordoba in the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check whether a list item exists in the string using `apply`:

```
import pandas as pd

obras = pd.DataFrame([['1','Agua de Buenos Aires'],['2', 'Sistenas de carreteras Jujuy'],['3','Reasentamiento en Entre Ríos'], ['4','Rutas en Córdoba']],columns = ['id', 'desc'])

list_ = ['Buenos Aires', 'Jujuy', 'Corrientes', 'Entre Ríos']
obras['localidad'] = obras['desc'].apply(lambda x: next(iter([i for i in list_ if i in x]), None))
```

Note that -given the desired output- this only returns the first match in case of multiple matches.

|  | id | desc | localidad |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | Agua de Buenos Aires | Buenos Aires |
| 1 | 2 | Sistenas de carreteras Jujuy | Jujuy |
| 2 | 3 | Reasentamiento en Entre Ríos | Entre Ríos |
| 3 | 4 | Rutas en Córdoba |  |

PS. don't use `list` as a variable name as it is also a builtin python function.

Comment: Thanx it really works! Can I ask you how do next and iter works?

Comment: Sure, it turns the list into an iterator, `next()` returns the next (in this case the first) item from the list, unless there is none, then it returns `None`. It's just a tweak to assign `None` in case there are no matches (ie. when the list is empty).